# How to get a single value from db using Fluent Hibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new to Fluent Hibernate And I'm stuck with a problem I want to get the email id of a user by using his user name means I want to implement the following code using fluent Hibernate

```
Select emailId from Table where username="User"
```

I tried the following code but its not give me what i want

```
public string ForgetPassword(string user)
{
    var factory = CreateSessionFactory();
    using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
    {
        var getEmail = session.Query<ClsAccountBL>()

           Select(u => u.Email).Where(u => u.User == user).ToString();
           return getMail; 
    }
 }
```

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.ToString()` use `FirstOrDefault()`. The LINQ does not return "single" element.

Comment: Select(u => u.Email).FirstOrDefault(); is working but Select(u => u.Email).Where(u => u.User == user).FirstOrDefault(); is not working  I cant add "where" closure with "Select" whats the reason behind this

Comment: Rorder your query it should be:  var getEmail = session.Query<ClsAccountBL>().Where(u => u.User == user).Select(u => u.Email).FirstOrDefault();